# scapy: UDP source port is changed after send

Tags: python, udp, port, scapy

I'm trying to build a script to test a self developed network protocol. Therefore I'm using scapy to send requests. Everything seems to work fine, but the UDP source port which I specify in my code seems to be changing during the sending process. The source port in Wireshark is not the same as the port which I've specified. I also tried to capture the packets with tcpdump, but tcpdump also shows me a wrong port.
I've checked the hexdump before sending and it also seems to be right. 
Any ideas what the problem is and how I can solve it?

```
for x in arr:
            cds = TestProtocol(HopCount = 0xe, Length = 0x4, Priority = 0x1, ServiceID = 0x3,
                            ReceiverAddrLen = 0x1, UniqueID1 = 0x1,
                            UniqueID2 = 0x1, SenderAddress = 0x1b4e,
                            PacketType = 0x02c2, data1 = 0x0004,
                            data2 = 0xe6a7, data3 = 0x0)
            ip = IP()
            ip.dst = destAddr
            ip.src = srcAddr
            udp = UDP()

            udp.sport = 1743 #the port which changes
            udp.dport = x
            pack = ip/udp/cds
            send(pack, verbose = True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would mean that your scapy module alters your port...what sense does this make?!

I do not even know "scapy" for udp communication and dont know what reason there would be to use it over pythons "socket"-module?

For UDP-transmissions I generally use

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.bind(('192.168.66.33', 6022))   #bind local IP and Port
s.sendto("Calling device", ('192.168.66.48', 6022)) #send string to other IP on same port
data,addr = s.recvfrom(4096) #buf size 4096 bytes
print str(data)   #print data received from called device
```

You could also use this for TCP stuff

Comment: The reason why I use scapy here is that with scapy you can easily manipulate packets send them to a specific host. This is really useful for penetration testing. My code also works according to wireshark. The only problem is the source port, which I have to set for sending correct requests.

Comment: In what way do you want to alter the packets? Change some bytes? Why isnt this possible with "socket"? you can receive the package, decode it, alter it, encode it and send it back

Comment: I have now combined scapy with the socket implementation of Python and it works. Thank you!

Comment: then please upvote or mark as useful answer! I need rep points man!